# Is the use of "bid" and "sell" as adjectives documented by any dictionary?

Tags: adjectives, dictionaries

E.g. "the market is very bid", meaning a bull market.

Comment: Nouns & verbs can be, and are often, used as qualifiers. The sentence is acceptable in contemporary use.

Comment: I've never seen *bid* used as an adjective, and I can't find any dictionary listing it (even the specialist financial dictionaries at OneLook.com). But Ngrams finds it: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bid_ADJ%2C+bullish&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbid_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbullish%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I suppose it's acceptable, and I suppose I wouldn't be surprised to see it in a dictionary, but that's not really saying much, is it. The real question is how common it is, and in which contexts, and what *your* context is. It clearly sounds like jargon at best, and like a Russian spy blowing his cover at worst, so whether it is in any dictionary, or indeed in every dictionary, is just a factoid that won't get you far. Especially not if you *are* a Russian spy.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: It's clearly used in a limited circle of bankers, and perhaps they *are* all Russian spies; they've done a darn good job of sabotage.

Comment: Just look in a dictionary

Comment: Now that I'm looking for it, I find news results using *bid* and *sell* as adjectives, particularly in phrases like "the market retained a *bid tone*", "markets open on *sell tone*", "central bank *sell interest* noted". I can't find this in dictionaries and I don't think I've ever heard anyone actually say these things aloud.

Comment: Its more typically bid and ask or bid and offer in financial markets jargon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one has actually produced a reference to an entry of "bid" or "sell" as adjectives it seems safe to claim that there isn't one. It hasn't been included in any typical, common dictionary that I searched. The term appears to be financial jargon and, presumably, it could be included in a dictionary of related terms. If someone does find such a reference they can post it here as a new answer.